# Quiz implementation using sleep() method of thread

Tags: java, multithreading

import java.util.Scanner;

import thread.QuestionPrompt;

public class Answer3 extends Thread{

```
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
static String [] ques = {"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj"};
static String [] ans = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};
    /**
 * @param args
 */


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] q=null;
    for(int i=0;i<ques.length;i++)
    {
    //q[i]=q[i](ques[i]);
    q[i].start();
    if (ques[i] != null)
        Thread.interrupt();
    }



}

public void run() {
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<ques.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println(ques[i]);

        Thread.sleep(30000);

        System.out.println("Time out..!!!!");
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        for(int i=0;i<ques.length;i++)
        {
        if (ques[i].equalsIgnoreCase(ans[i]))
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations...!!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time...!!!!");

        }
        }

    }
}}
```

Using sleep() method, how above code can be modified to play a quiz and get result of a candidate? 
Any solution..

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the problem with the code you are showing us here?

Comment: i want the code implementaion for quiz using thread

Comment: This is not a code request site. If you have a specific problem, describe it in detail together with instructions on how to reproduce it. Otherwise, your question will most probably be closed.

Comment: ok bro... i want that a single thread execute in this program and each question is passed from string[] ques as in my code and for each question 30 seconds are given...so how to do this??

Comment: Showing how to do this exceeds the usual length of an answer here in SO. Look into java.util.Timer and read some tutorial on thread synchronisation. - But are you sure that you want to dig into these rather advanced concepts at your present level of programming experience?

Comment: thanks but no need for java.util.Timer, i just have to display 10 questions and each question should be displayed for 30 seconds..after that next question and so on...so if u can tell wat could be done in this..please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi first of all you need to see threading because your code is let say anything but not threading so here is the code of the thread that you need
try to understand please:

```
  /*
   * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
   * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
   * and open the template in the editor.
   */
   package Application;

   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;


   /**
   *
   * @author husseyn
   */

 public class quiz {

static Scanner keyboard;
static Thread reader;
static String answer;
static String[] questions={"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6"};
static String[] answers={"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6"};

static boolean wait=false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("welcome to quiz v1.0");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(quiz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            int questionIndex=0;
            while (true) {                    

                try {

                    questionIndex=(int)(Math.random()*questions.length);

                    System.out.println(questions[questionIndex]);
            //        System.out.println("your answer : ");

                    int count=0;
                    wait=true;
                    while (wait) {                        
                    sleep(1000);
                    count++;
                        //System.out.print(count+" ");
                        if (count==10) {

                    reader.stop();
                    wait=false;
                        }
                }

                    wait=false;
              if(answers[questionIndex].toLowerCase().trim().equals(answer.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        System.out.println("congratulation");
                    }else{
                        if (answer.equals("")) {
                            System.out.println("you r an idio try harder");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("good try but answer is false :p next time");
                        }
                    }
                    answer="";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        }

    }.start();


    new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                while (!wait) {
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(quiz.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    try {

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    System.out.print("answer: ");
                    reader=new Thread(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            answer=keyboard.nextLine();
                            wait=false;
                        }

                    };
                    reader.run();

                }



            }
        }

    }.start();
}

}
```

Comment: try to edit the code i used random question loop and 10 seconds for the time try to understand and manage the code for your need. i did it on purpose to leave you a little work

Comment: ones you understand threading try to look on timerTask is really usefull

Comment: please validate my answer if you found it useful

Comment: i have validated...your code helped a lot